# Connected components in flat families

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow S$ be a proper flat family of schemes with non-empty geometrically reduced fibers and $S$ Noetherian integral scheme. Is it true that $X$ has finitely many subschemes such that the restriction of $f$ to each of them is a proper and flat family of schemes over $S$ with non-empty geometrically connected and geometrically reduced fibers?

Comment: No. Consider $X=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}(i))$ and $S=\mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Actually, I think that the way the question is phrased,  the answer is yes. It is certainly true that $X$ has *finitely* many subschemes such that [...]. (In fact, this is always true, because the empty set is a finite set.) In my above comment, I interpreted your question as asking for the existence of *some* subscheme such that [...].  With this being said, could you please clarify what you precisely are looking for?